# What is the equivalent to rpart.plot in Python? I want to visualize the results of my random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, random-forest, decision-tree

In `[R]`, you can visualize the results of your random forest like so (image shamelessly stolen from the internet). What is the equivalent in Python? I can get the results of my sklearn random forest classification using `feature_importances_` , but I want to know which direction they send the result. I realize with a deep forest I won't be able to examine every branch, but maybe it can weight the probabilities? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do not use foreigen IP! Respect copyright (or copyleft: state the licence)

Comment: I don't think rpart does random forests.  It makes *single* decision trees.  There's no simple way to make such a diagram for a random forest, because a random forest includes many decision trees, some of which may even be using different subsets of the input variables.

Comment: I thought the mode result was a tree itself, is that not true? It isn't eventually using a decision tree structure in its prediction?

Comment: It use many weak tree classifier to do a majority vote, and every tree classifier has different threshold parameters. This is why it's impossible to generate a decision tree plot in random forest.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, @JianxunLi, but it uses many *strong* tree classifiers. It's an important difference between bagging (which is what random forests are doing) and boosting (which uses weak learners).

Answer (score 4):

Use the parameters of tree.export_graphviz, see this example and image result:

```
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out, feature_names=['alcohol', 'income'],class_names=['0','1'], 
                     filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True)

graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(out.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Image Result

[image]

See the [jupyter notebook on github](https://github.com/Sidon/Sidon.github.io/blob/master/_posts/dtree-w1.ipynb) and [project details](https://sidon.github.io/dtree-week1/).

Comment: Is there a way to ommit the values in Python? I find these graphs unreadable in my use cases.